# How to connect to SSH EC2 Amazon even if port 22 is already set up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

Im getting Timeout error on ssh connection to EC2 even after set port 22 to anywhere, i see my user and is ec2-user indeed but im getting timeout everytime

Im already tried reboot the instance and change to other security group, even try Termius software (im on MAC) instead command line but notheing...

Comment: Is your EC2 instance running in an internet-facing VPC?

Comment: how i see this ? i have this information on EC2 description VPC ID
vpc-551fb82e

Comment: Select you VPC (https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home?region=us-east-1#subnets) and check if an internet gateway is attached within your "Route Table"

Comment: can i delete this ? to allow all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check you VPC and subnets inside this VPC in which you have created your instance. The subnet will have a route table, verify that subnet is attached to an Internet Gateway with Destination `0.0.0.0/0`, otherwise add one by referring [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html#Add_IGW_Attach_Gateway) link. Post this step, check that your security group has an Ingress Rule for port 22 from your ip(select `my ip` from drop down). You will not get `Connection timeout error` if these two steps are configured properly.